# How to migrate a client-side "authentication verification" system to the new app router?

Tags: next.js, jwt

Since the app router became stable I decided to migrate from the old pages folder.

Previous to the app router a common approach was to use the getserversideprops function to determine whether or not the user is logged in. If he is not then he is redirected to the login page (and vice-versa).

How does one achieve this same result in the new app router?

Can someone please provide an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would do the same thing in a server component. Instead of using server side props you can now create an asynchronous server component that replicates the same behavior.

```
import "server-only";
import { redirect } from next/navigation;

interface Props extends React.PropsWithChildren {}

// will render children if authenticated and 
// redirect to login otherwise.
async function AuthRedirect({ children }: Props): Promise<JSX.Element> {
  const auth = await getAuth();
  if (!auth) redirect("/login");
  return <>{children}</>;
}

export default AuthRedirect;
export type { Props as AuthRedirectProps };
```

Given the above example you could just import this component into any page you only want to display to authenticated users and wrap your page content with it.

###### Important note

The `server-only` package needs to be installed separately, it is used to throw an error if you try to use a server component on the client side.

Comment: But how I would pass down information from this server component to its child components? (the child components are client components). With the getServerSideProps I could simply return the information I want to pass to the component and it would be available as props. Now I need to define 2 components on the same file?

Comment: I need to decode the token from the cookies (which contain information about the current user) and pass down to the other components

Comment: You can simply import a client component in to a server component and pass it as props.

Comment: Thanks! I marked your answer as a solution.

Comment: Is it just me or the old approach was easier and more intuitive? It seems kinda cumbersome to create a whole new component and wrap everything on it instead of declaring the getServerSideProps at the beginning. What do you think?

Comment: Well, the new pattern allows you to create zero initial JS components since server components only ever render on the server and this approach really helps with SEO and bundle size issues.